# Can I use a notation for an Inductive type to define that type in Coq?

Tags: coq, notation, dependent-type

Suppose I've got something like this:

```
Inductive SubtypeOf :
  Gamma -> UnsafeType -> Type -> Set :=
| SubRefl :
    forall (gamma : GammaEnv)  (u : UnsafeType)
    , SubtypeOf gamma u u
| SubTrans :
    forall (gamma : GammaEnv)  (u1 u2 u3 : Type)
    , SubtypeOf gamma u1 u2
      -> SubtypeOf gamma u2 u3
      -> SubtypeOf gamma u1 u3.
```

And a notation defined:

`Notation "G |-  x <: y " := (SubtypeOf G x y) (at level 50).`

Is there any way I can bring this notation into scope for the definition of `SubtypeOf`, so I could do something like this:

```
Inductive SubtypeOf :
  Gamma -> UnsafeType -> Type -> Set :=
| SubRefl :
    forall (gamma : GammaEnv)  (u : UnsafeType)
    ,  gamma |- u <: u
| SubTrans :
    forall (gamma : GammaEnv)  (u1 u2 u3 : Type)
    , gamma |- u1 <: u2
      -> gamma |- u2 <: u3
      -> gamma |- u1 <: u3.
```

Comment: Yes, look for `Reserved Notation` and `where` in the Coq manual.

Comment: @ejgallego Perfect, put this as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on ejgallego's comment, there is documentation for [`Reserved Notation`s](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.6.1/refman/Reference-Manual014.html#hevea_command218) and [a `where` clause for inductives](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.6.1/refman/Reference-Manual014.html#hevea_command221).  Here is code that works:

```
Reserved Notation "G |-  x <: y" (at level 50, x at next level).
Definition UnsafeType := Type.
Axiom Gamma : Set.
Notation GammaEnv := Gamma.
Inductive SubtypeOf :
  Gamma -> UnsafeType -> Type -> Type :=
| SubRefl :
    forall (gamma : GammaEnv)  (u : UnsafeType)
    ,  gamma |- u <: u
| SubTrans :
    forall (gamma : GammaEnv)  (u1 u2 u3 : Type)
    , gamma |- u1 <: u2
      -> gamma |- u2 <: u3
      -> gamma |- u1 <: u3
where "G |-  x <: y " := (SubtypeOf G x y).
```

Note that we must put `x` at the next level (49), so that the `<:` gets parsed with `|-`, rather than being absorbed into `x`.